# Python urllib2 error reading

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am attempting to write a simple program that uses urllib2 with some error handling. The code looks like the below

```
try:
    urllib2.Request(...)
except HTTPError as e:
    self.log.debug("HTTP Error for url %s is %s" % (e.url, e.read()))
```

The point is to just dump the error page in full in addition to the e.message. However occasionally I get the message `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 4030: ordinal not in range(128)` which I believe is because the e.read() is assuming ascii char set of the contents where as the returned page probably has something else.

My question is how do I fix this? i.e, I would like to have a "reasonably" informative message dumped. I agree that this would also depend on the charset and encoding returned by the URL I am attempting to connect to but if there is any way in my Python e.read method to not attempt to ensure ASCII chars

Comment: If `self.log` is a reference to a standard logging object, you should not do string interpolation, but pass the interpolations as parameters: `log.debug('blah %s is %s', e.url, e.read())`. Does that help?

Comment: It is not a standard logging object. What if I just wanted to print instead? Sorry I don't see how that is going to help?

Comment: Because your diagnosis of the problem is faulty. `e.read()` is not assuming anything about characters, and does not care. It is the string interpolation that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use encode and it will work, it's just a problem with the encoding.

```
try:
    urllib2.Request(...)
except HTTPError as e:
    self.log.debug("HTTP Error for url %s is %s" % (e.url, e.read().encode('utf8')))
```